# Can anyone tell me why this keeps resulting to 0? (C program)

Tags: c

```
    case 2:
        if(hrswrk <= 40)
            pay = wage * hrswrk;
        else
            pay = (40 * wage) + (hrswrk - 40) * (wage * 1.5);
        printf("Hourly Workers is selected. \n");
        printf("Enter number of hours worked: \n");
        scanf("%i",&hrswrk);
        printf("Enter hourly wage: \n");
        scanf("%i",&wage);
        printf("Your pay is Php%.2f",pay);
        break;
```

This is just a part of my program and its frustrating that I can't even solve this, maybe the mistake is that I placed an if else statement within a switch? I'm so lost.

Comment: This isn't a complete example, and you're not explaining just what is "resulting to 0".  For one, you're not checking *any* return values from `scanf()` so you don't know if they worked at all.

Comment: Most likely you are mixing integers and float. This can't be answered without the variable declarations.

Answer (score 2):

Do your operations after you get required data:

```
case 2:
    printf("Hourly Workers is selected. \n");
    printf("Enter number of hours worked: \n");
    scanf("%i",&hrswrk);
    printf("Enter hourly wage: \n");
    scanf("%i",&wage);

    if(hrswrk <= 40)
        pay = wage * hrswrk;
    else
        pay = (40 * wage) + (hrswrk - 40) * (wage * 1.5);

    printf("Your pay is Php%.2f",pay);
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute `pay` *after* the values for `hrswrk` and `wage` have been established, i.e. move the `if` block *after* the final `scanf` call.

Although some languages work the way you have written it, C doesn't.

Note also that you should always check the return value of `scanf`, in order to check if the reading has been successful.

Comment: curious to know what languages work this way.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: You can get C++ to do this using *actors*. See Boost Phoenix for an established use case.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your `if-condition` after `scanf()`

In your code you are executing `if-condition` before reading `hrswrk` and `wage`. Read them first and execute the `if-logic`.

Try this modified code :-

```
case 2:
    printf("Hourly Workers is selected. \n");
    printf("Enter number of hours worked: \n");
    scanf("%i", &hrswrk);
    printf("Enter hourly wage: \n");
    scanf("%i", &wage); 

    if (hrswrk <= 40)   // if condition after scanning wage and  hrswrk
        pay = wage * hrswrk;
    else
        pay = (40 * wage) + (hrswrk - 40) * (wage * 1.5);
    printf("Your pay is Php%.2f", pay);
    break;
```

This will work.

Comment: `if` is not a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 case 2:
        printf("Hourly Workers is selected. \n");
        printf("Enter number of hours worked: \n");
        scanf("%i",&hrswrk);
        printf("Enter hourly wage: \n");
        scanf("%i",&wage);
       if(hrswrk <= 40)
            pay = wage * hrswrk;
        else
            pay = (40 * wage) + (hrswrk - 40) * (wage * 1.5);
        printf("Your pay is Php%.2f",pay);
        break;
```